# Remove Items from Multiple ListBoxes Relative to Index of one ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am new to C# and want to Remove an Item from three `ListBoxes` but at the same index as from the first `ListBox`

In my case suppose I have 3 `ListBoxes` and I will get the index of an item from the First `ListBox` e.g. 2. Now I want to *Remove* the item at Index 2 from all 3 `ListBoxes`. The problem is that I have successfully removed the item from the selected index in `ListBox` 1 but not from other 2 `ListBoxes` my code is:

```
public static int indextodelete;

private void List1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove \"" + glossarywords.SelectedItem + "\" as a non specific word?", "Domain Expert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if ( result1 == DialogResult.Yes )
    {
        indextodelete = List1.Items.IndexOf(List1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        List1.Items.Remove(List1.SelectedItem);
        List2.Items.Remove(indextodelete);
        List3.Items.Remove(indextodelete);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
List2.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
List3.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
```

> Removes the item at the specified index within the collection.

[MSDN Documentation for RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`.Remove()` takes the full object to remove, not the index. `RemoveAt()` takes the index.

Full modified method:

```
public static int indextodelete;
private void List1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove \"" + glossarywords.SelectedItem + "\" as a non specific word?", "Domain Expert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // remove based on object
        List1.Items.Remove(List1.SelectedItem);

        indextodelete = List1.Items.IndexOf(List1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        // remove based on index.
        List2.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
        List3.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need RemoveAt method for 2 other listboxes:

```
List1.Items.Remove(List1.SelectedItem);
List2.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
List3.Items.RemoveAt(indextodelete);
```